# Why does this "factorial sequence" appear in the OEIS?

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, integer-sequences, oeis

For a reciprocal of a polynomial, $f = \frac{1}{p}$, we (presumably) may construct a sequence $(c_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ such that for all $N\ge 0$
$$f(k)k! = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} c_n(k-n)! + O((k-N)!). $$
I ask about constructing such sequences in [Calculating "factorial sequence" of a rational function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378103/calculating-factorial-sequence-of-a-rational-function).

Through some messy calculations, I get $$c_0,c_1,\dotsc = 0,0,0,0,1,-2,7,-32,179,-1182,8993,-77440,744425,-7901410,\dotsc$$ when $f = \frac{1}{(k-1)(k(k-1)(k-2)-k)}$. It just so happens that $\lvert c_{i+3}\rvert = a(i)$ for the OEIS [A265165](http://oeis.org/A265165). I have tried looking at [Banderier, Baril, and Dos Santos - Right-jumps & pattern avoiding permutations](https://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/%7Ebanderier/Papers/rightjump.pdf) which the OEIS page links, but I couldn't see a reason why these should yield the same sequence. Can you find one? (Funnily enough, I came across this sequence $c_n$ by considering permutations, but in a totally different setting than the paper.)

Also, are "factorial sequences" $(c_n)$ a concept which has been studied before? Are there any other interesting OEIS sequences that happen to have a factorial sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$\frac{1}{x}f(\frac1x) = \sum_{n\geq 1} (F_{2n-3}-1)x^n,$$
where $F_{2n+1}$ are Fibonacci numbers.
Per [answers](https://mathoverflow.net/a/378165) to [your previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378103/calculating-factorial-sequence-of-a-rational-function), it follows that
$$c_{n+1} = \sum_{i=0}^n s(n,i) (F_{2i-3}-1).$$

For $n\geq 2$, "$-1$" can be dropped, reducing the formula to
$$c_{n+1} = \sum_{i=0}^n s(n,i) F_{2i-3}.$$

Using the generating function for Stirling numbers and Binet's formula for Fibonacci numbers, we obtain the following exponential generating function for $c_{n+1}$:
$$\sum_{n\geq 0} c_{n+1} \frac{z^n}{n!} = \frac{(1+z)^{1+\phi}(2\phi-3)+(1+z)^{2-\phi}(2\phi+1)}{\sqrt{5}}-1,$$
where $\phi\mathrel{:=}\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2$. Under substitution of $z=-x$, this matches the e.g.f. given in the sequence [OEIS A265165](https://oeis.org/A265165), and so they do represent the same sequence (up to signs and shift of indices).

Comment: There were two answers to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378103/calculating-factorial-sequence-of-a-rational-function , and I couldn't quite tell if you meant to link to one or both; but @PietroMajer's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/378165) seemed closer, so I edited in the link to that.  Please feel free to fix it if I got it wrong.

Comment: @LSpice: We need both as Pietro's answer builds on Fedor's one. Btw, I've added a generalization of what I said here as yet another answer there.